# Why are the small barcode stickers placed on checked bags sometimes nicknamed "bingo tags" or " bingo stickers"?

Tags: phrases

Why are the small barcode stickers placed on checked bags sometimes nicknamed  "bingo tags" or " bingo stickers"? Is that somehow a reference to the Bingo game? Or the bingo! expression? Or some other reference?

I saw that expression used on:

- [What's the point in placing small barcode stickers on one's check-in bags?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/131522/1810)
- http://www.slate.com/articles/life/design/2012/10/airline_baggage_tags_how_their_brilliant_design_gets_bags_from_point_a_to_point_b_.html
- https://www.ausbt.com.au/this-simple-trick-helps-ensure-your-suitcase-arrives-on-the-belt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a commonly used expression, but a piece of baggage handler jargon.

A bingo card, for use in the game, is a card with random numbers printed on it in a square grid of boxes (usually 5x5). As the numbers are called, you mark off the numbers on your card.

When they are loading bags onto airplanes, they peel of a sticker from each bag, and stick it onto a piece of paper. The paper has a grid of boxes on it. The grid of boxes  (and filling up the grid with markers) reminded people of bingo cards, so they called the stickers "bingo tags".

But this is not a commonly known expression, so it is an example of "jargon".